# a matrice that becomes zero when multiplied with its factor

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, matrices

suppose there is a group of matrices. these matrices multiplied result in a matrix in the group. the matrix can be divided in only one unique way of multiplication of some matrices in the group. we call these factors. when a matrix is multiplied with one of its factor matrices, the mattix becomes zero matrix.

so, is there any group of matrix satisfies this property?

Comment: Restating your question for rings, is there a factorial matrix ring with zero divisors? No, all factorial rings are integral.

Answer (score 1):

No group of matrices can contain the zero matrix, as the zero matrix does not have an inverse...

Comment: Well the singleton of a zero matrix actually forms a trivial group...

Comment: Okay, right. I should have written "no nontrivial group of..."

Answer (score 0):

Your question is rather unclear (the word group is not in place for instance) but you seem to be asking for a subring of a matrix ring that has unique factorization and also zero divisors. However factorzation does not mesh well with the presence of zero divisors: if one factor in a product is a zero divisor, you can always add its complementary zero divisor to the *other* factor without changing the product, thus ruling out unique factorization. In fact for divisibility questions one almost always supposes the ring is a domain.